# apache2 on ubuntu 18x - how to add a subdomain but enable forwarding to https?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2, ubuntu-18.04

I have two sites-enabled and configged per below.  It all works well.  `http` gets forwarded to `https` and `example.com` gets forwarded to `www.example.com`.  I now want to add a subdomain called `development.example.com` but I cannot stop it from getting forwarded to `https://www.example.com` instead of `https://development.example.com`

Here is my config so far:

filename:  `example.com.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName example.com
   Redirect permanent http://example.com https://www.example.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin info@example.com
    ServerName  example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com.access.log combined
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

and another for https as follows;

filename: `example.com-le-ssl.conf`

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName example.com
   Redirect permanent https://example.com https://www.example.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin info@example.com
    ServerName  example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com.access.log combined
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
   </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

but now I want to add a subdomain called `development.example.com`.  I added the following configs;

filename:  `development.example.com.conf` and `development.example.com-le-ssl.conf`

The above two configs are the same as the 2 far above but with `development` in front of the domain, however, when I enter http or https plus `developement.example.com` it gets forwarded to `https://www.example.com`.

How can I fix this please?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, you could use just one config file instead.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain.example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://subdomain.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/certificate.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/private.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/intermediate.crt

    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName subdomain.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/certificate.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/private.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/intermediate.crt

    <Directory /var/www/subdomain>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Where the first two blocks listen on port 80 and auto redirect traffic with "Redirect permanent" to https, respectively to your domain or subdomain.

Just to include one more thing, I'm not sure if you are using real domain or just fake one in testing environment but proper dns rules are needed for subdomain to work.